# Node Express - requesting any file returns 404 not found

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-lightsail

I have deployed an AWS LightSail Node server with Express on it.
Starting the app on port 3000 correctly activates app.js and display in the browser the projected string (http://my.ip.address:3000):
**Welcome to the Whiteboard server! this is the home page on port 3000 with base dir: /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/whiteboard**

This is the app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

global.__basedir = __dirname;

app.use(express.json());
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Whiteboard listening on port: ${port}`);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Welcome to the Whiteboard server! this is the home page on port ${port} with base dir: ${__basedir}`);
});
```

However, Trying to request any file residing in the root folder (...apache/htdocs/whiteboard) such as:

http://my.ip.address:3000/Jeanette_Blog1.png

http://my.ip.address:3000/index.html

Always returns this message in the browser:

***Cannot GET /Jeanette_Blog1.png***

Shows as 404 error in the console.

Btw, although the path shows apache, I have actually installed node with needed modules and express - as can be seen in the app.js file up here. The apache is just part of the node image AWS LightSail creates through their partner Bitnami.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An express server by itself does not serve any files by default.  If you want to serve a directory or a directory hierarchy of static files, you have to use `express.static()` (or something similar) in a route definition.

You should not configure `express.static()` to point at the same directory that contains your server code because that would enable people to look at your server files.  It is a popular convention to make a sub-directory (often called "/public", either below or at the same level as your server files.  Here's an example with `express.static()` configured for a directory at the same level.  You would add this line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
```

And, it would all look like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = 3000;

global.__basedir = __dirname;

// serve public files    
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")), {index: false});

app.use(express.json());
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Whiteboard listening on port: ${port}`);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Welcome to the Whiteboard server! this is the home page on port ${port} with base dir: ${__basedir}`);
});
```

Then, you would move your static files such  as `index.html` and `Jeanette_Blog1.png` to that `/public` directory.  They can be referred to from the browser as URLS such as `/index.html` and `/Jeanette_Blog1.png`.  The `express.static()` middleware will check the incoming path to see if it matches a filename in the `/public` directory and, if so, it will serve it.  If it doesn't match a file, then it will continue routing to other route handlers you have defined.

Comment: Thanks, jfriend! and where would I install the node_modules, such as socket.io needed by my app? seems they also need to be under "public", but they're also needed to start the node server in the app folder...

Comment: @MorSagmon - You would do `npm install socket.io` from within your server directory `...apache/htdocs/whiteboard`.  This will actually install the server-side of socket.io in the `node_modules` sub-directory below your server files where the node module loader can find the code for your server-side use.   But, socket.io will also automatically install a route for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` to serve the client-side socket.io.js for you.  You don't have to mange the client-side files for socket.io as the socket.io server code does that automatically.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! Installed socket.io, but a client js file (in "public") also requires it, and it is not available in public. Getting this 404 in console: GET http://54.235.198.51:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=O9p-crZ

Comment: @MorSagmon - Yes, your js files will need to be in `/public` or something similar. The error you refer to sounds like your socket.io client or server code is not properly configured or installed.  That would be the subject of another question I think as it appears your socket.io server is not listening or is being blocked.

Comment: Many thanks! I'll work this out... :)